# Erro ao inserir dados no banco com Jquery e Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

Este trecho de código sempre retorna ERRO: 200.
Ele está inserindo os dados no banco normalmente, mas retorna erro na interface.

```
    $("#registrar").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url : "registra.php",
            method: "POST",
            dataType : "json",
            data : {participante1 : $("#participante1 option:selected").val(),
                    participante2 : $("#participante2 option:selected").val(),
                    score1 : $("#score1").val(),
                    score2 : $("#score2").val()},

            success : function(resp){
                alert("Registro efetuado com sucesso!");
            },

            error : function(err){
                alert("ERRO: " + err.status);
            }
        });
    });
```

Código PHP:

```
<?php 
    $con = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=Jogos user=postgres password=postgres");
    $participante1 = $_POST['participante1'];
    $participante2 = $_POST['participante2'];
    $score1 = $_POST['score1'];
    $score2 = $_POST['score2'];
    $comando = "INSERT INTO disputas (participante1, participante2, score1, score2) 
                VALUES ('$participante1', '$participante2', '$score1', '$score2')";
    pg_query($con, $comando);
    pg_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Estranho o código de erro ser 200, mas tente adicionar no PHP a linha: `http_response_code(200)` e veja se muda algo.

Comment: Não mudou nada, continua apresentando o mesmo erro.

Comment: Ok, você configurou a resposta para ser JSON, mas o PHP não retorna um JSON válido. Provavelmente funcionará se alterar para `text` ou fazer o PHP retornar um JSON válido.

Comment: Alterei para text e funcionou. Muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse comportamento acontece quando você define o retorno esperado como JSON em:

```
dataType : "json"
```

porém o servidor não retorna um JSON válido. Desta forma, o jQuery, ao analisar o retorno, considera que houve erro e dispará a função `error`, mesmo com o código HTTP de retorno 200. Para corrigir isso, basta modificar o tipo de retorno para `text` ou fazer o PHP retornar um JSON válido.

Ou seja, faça:

```
$("#registrar").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url : "registra.php",
        method: "POST",
        dataType : "text",
        data : {participante1 : $("#participante1 option:selected").val(),
                participante2 : $("#participante2 option:selected").val(),
                score1 : $("#score1").val(),
                score2 : $("#score2").val()},

        success : function(resp){
            alert("Registro efetuado com sucesso!");
        },

        error : function(err){
            alert("ERRO: " + err.status);
        }
    });
});
```